# Examples from everyday life for diastereoisomers ?

Tags: stereochemistry

Like the amino-acids and sugars that are enantiomers, can you give any examples of diastereoisomers ? where can we find them in everyday life ?

Comment: Amino acids and sugars have other isomers than enantiomers aswell. The diastereomer is a type of stereoisomer. These would occur with  amino acids and sugars too. Diastereomerism occurs when two or more stereoisomers of a compound have different configurations at one or more (but not all) of the equivalent (related) stereocentres and are not mirror images of each other. Ref: diastereomer/wiki.com

Comment: D-threose and D-erythrose are diastereomers. Ref:diastereomer/wiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nowadays, it's really easy to find information on the Internet or in books. Being resourceful and being able to search for stuff yourself will help you greatly.

Nevertheless...

## Carbohydrates

Glucose and galactose, two of the most common monosaccharides found in the body, are diastereomers of each other:

[image: Glucose vs galactose]

Lactose, which is found in milk, is formed by a condensation reaction between glucose and galactose.

## Eyesight

Retinal is a molecule found in the photoreceptor cells of eyes that normally exists in the 11-*cis* form. When it absorbs light, it undergoes an isomerisation to form the all-*trans* form:

[image: Retinal]

This forms part of the biochemical pathway by which light is converted into an electrical signal in the nervous system.